# What is the maximum level cap in Apex Legends?

Tags: apex-legends

I've been playing Apex Legends for a little while, and have made it up to level 32. Each time I've gained a level I've been rewarded with 600 legend tokens [image]. I've seen a few people mention there being a maximum level, but nobody has said what it is. I'm curious because I'd like to know how many more tokens I'll be able to earn, before I need to start spending money to unlock new legends.

What is the maximum account level in Apex Legends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is currently **500**, up from the original cap of 100:

> **What do I get when I increase my Player Level?  What is the maximum Player Level?**
>
> Players can increase their Player Level by earning XP from playing matches. Each time a player levels up, they will earn rewards like an Apex Pack, Legend Tokens, or both.
>
> Starting December 3, player Level caps at 500. After reaching Level 500, players can earn additional Legend Tokens by gaining enough XP during matches.
>
> ― [Apex Legends FAQ](https://www.ea.com/games/apex-legends/about/frequently-asked-questions#q2)

Answer (score 3):

It has been increased to 500.

https://www.ea.com/games/apex-legends/news/progression-changes